# JAVASCRIPT DFS of Graph

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an iterative DFS but I can't seem to add items to the visited set?
After, I will try to do a recursive DFS. I'm not uite sure what I am doing wrong here. Assistance would be greatly appreciated. <3

```
const adjList = {
  1: [2, 5],
  2: [1, 3, 5],
  3: [2, 4],
  4: [3, 5, 6],
  5: [1, 2, 4],
  6: [4]
}
```

```
function printDepthFirst(start, visited = new Set()) {
  // your code here
  let adj = adjList;


        const stack = [];
        stack.push(start);
        visited.add(start)
        let visitedArr = [];


        while(stack.length) {

            let Node = stack.pop();
            visitedArr.push(Node)
            console.log(" Visited Node: " + Node)
            
            let neighbors = adj[Node]

            
            

            
            for (let i = 0; i < neighbors.length; i++) {
                if (!visited.has(neighbors[i])) {
                stack.push(neighbors[i]);
                }
            }
            neighbors.forEach(neighbor => visited.add(neighbor))
        }
        console.log("Visited Nodes: " + JSON.stringify([...visited]))
        console.log("VisstedArr: " + visitedArr)
        return false;
    }
```

```
console.log("First Test:")
printDepthFirst(3); // Prints 1 through 6 in Depth-first order, starting with 3
                    // One possible solution:  3, 4, 6, 5, 1, 2
console.log("Second Test:")
printDepthFirst(6); // Prints 1 through 6 in Depth-first order, starting with 6
                    // One possible solution:  6, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3
console.log("Third Test:")
printDepthFirst(4); // Prints 1 through 6 in Depth-first order, starting with 4
                    // One possible solution:  4, 6, 5, 2, 1, 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the neighbors to the `visited` set to early: all of them during the first iteration! This means that on the subsequent iterations, none of the other neighbors will be added to the stack. It should be either

```
for (let i = 0; i < neighbors.length; i++) {
    if (!visited.has(neighbors[i])) {
        stack.push(neighbors[i]);
        visited.add(neighbors[i]))
    }
}
```

or

```
for (let i = 0; i < neighbors.length; i++) {
    if (!visited.has(neighbors[i])) {
        stack.push(neighbors[i]);
    }
}
neighbors.forEach(neighbor => visited.add(neighbor))
```

(Another approach, a bit closer to the recursive version, would be to always add all of the neighbors - possibly just as the whole array - to the stack, and check whether they had already been visited only when popping them from the stack)

Btw, another problem that leads to your code implementing a BFS rather than a DFS is the use of `stack.shift()`. You're using the array as a queue, not as a stack, it should be `stack.pop()`!

Comment: Thanks for the information Bergi, I can't seem to get it to print out the Visited Nodes list with the code you gave witht he forEach statement, I edited the original snippet so you can see what I've done.

Comment: Is that a scope problem, is that what I'm doing wrong? XD

Comment: You broke the `console.log` again (it should be `JSON.stringify(Array.from(visited))` or `JSON.stringify([...visited])`, not `JSON.stringify(...visited)`), but I guess your main problem is that you're not adding the neighbor nodes to the `visited` set in the same order (forward) as you are traversing them (backwards). Look only at the output of the `console.log("Node: " + Node)` instead.

Comment: Thank you again for the explaination. I really do appreciate your patience and time.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` is not working for sets because the data stored in the set is not stored as properties.

To properly print set, you should do:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify([...s]));
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Do you know why my algorithm is printing in BFS rather than DFS?